# New Target and App for AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode4, app-store

I am so confused about the how to configure my second App for the App store. I have a one App which I am basing my second app on, I duplicated the target and some classes, modified it and checked it all the time in the simulator. Now I need to test it on my iPhone and then submit to the app store but I don't understand what I need to do about the following:

1) When I duplicated the Target for "myApp" I got a new file under the Products group in Xcode called "myApp copy.app", "copy-myApp-info.plist" and new scheme called "myApp copy". I was able to change the name of the info.plist.

If I then select my target and go to "Info"

2) The Bundle Identifier is exactly the same as my original.

3) The Executable file still says "${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" (without the quotes)

4) The Bundle display name still says "${PRODUCT_NAME}"

5) The Bundle name still says "${PRODUCT_NAME}"

What do I need to change above in order to release my new target as a new app in the AppStore? Also, will I need new provisioning profiles and certificates for this second target/app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow below steps in order to test the application in device.

- Duplicate the target and change the name as well.
- Change the app name in schema by clicking manage schema button.
- Change the product name and version whichever you want.
- Create the new appID in developer portal.
- Create the provisioning profiles based on the identifier.
- Change the bundle identifier name in the new target.
- Change the code signing profiles in build setting tab.

Note: If you run the app in simulator that doesn't care about the profiles. If you run the app in device you defiantly take care about the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to set new bundle identifier for your new app, then create new project on iTunes connect. You can change all parameter of new target relevant to your new app. After that your are ready to build new app with changes.